# Git how to overwrite directory with updated files

Tags: git, tortoisegit

In my project I have subdirectory 'generated-src' that contain a lot of source files generated by other app. Then at some point I need to update this directory with the new version.

So I have two directories that contains mostly the same files but some of them could be different/missing/added.

What would be the best method to update the directory ? Simply deleting 'generated-src' and copy new one create various results depending on the Git client ( SourceTree is able to compare the contents and stage only the differences, Tortoise has some problems ).

Thanks.

Comment: What problems on TortoiseGit?

Comment: Try to use **git submodule**.

Let that `generated-src` as a independent repository and embed it into your project. After this, you can update generated-src folder more easier.

Answer (score 0):

First you should

> git add generated-src/*

And then you should

> git commit